# Can an older bill be picked up and voted on by a new congress?

Tags: united-states, congress, legislative-process, stimulus

Before the new congress took over in January 2021; the House of Representatives passed a standalone bill to increase the $600 stimulus payments to $2000, by sending an additional $1400 to every eligible adult. The bill was never considered for vote because McConnell would not take it up in the Senate. Now that the there is a new majority leader; could the Senate choose to simply vote on that bill that was already passed by the House? Given that it was something president Trump actually asked for; it seems likely that it would have bipartisan support, possibly enough to defeat a filibuster.

Is this an option for the current Senate; or is it not allowed because it was a previous congress in which the bill passed in the House?